# sed command to search string and append a line after searched string

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have a file test, with the content

```
Hi
Hello 
I am good.
```

My requirement is I have to write a shell script to search `Hello` sting in the file test and add a new line after it with the content `got it`.

For this I am using command:

```
sed '/Hello/ a "got it"' test
```

I am getting the below error for this command:

> sed: command garbled: /Hello/ a "got it"

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
sed '/Hello/a got it' file
```

`a` is append command. read `man sed` for detail

test with your example:

```
kent$  echo "Hi
Hello 
I am good."|sed '/Hello/a got it'
Hi
Hello 
got it
I am good.
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be necessary to escape second double quotes? `a \"got it\" '`?

Comment: `a \

       text   Append text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a backslash.`

Comment: @Kent I am still getting the same error after trying with sed '/Hello/ a \"got it"' test.

Comment: @kent This answer is little confusing. OP is not looking for double quotes in the new append and might confuse new visitors.

Answer (score 0):

@Kishore, your "command garbled" error probably indicates that you used an "AltGr + Space" instead of a space when typing your command, or that you failed to use regular upright single quotes.

In fact the spaces are not necessary at all, and if you just want to put "got it" on the line following the match, just go:

```
sed '/Hello/agot it' test
```

It works perfectly well, the backslash in @Kent's solution is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

## A general answer to the asked question

**sed command to search string and append a line after searched string**

You can use [regex capture groups](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2022/10/13/advanced-regex-capture-groups-lookaheads-and-lookbehinds).
In sed you have to escape the parenthesis.
To reuse the captured content you can use `\1` (1 for the number of the capture - afaik up to 9 in sed )

generally it looks like:

```
echo "barfoobaz" > /tmp/file
sed -i 's/bar\(foo\)baz/ new \1 text/g' /tmp/file
cat /tmp/file
# new foo text
```

How to add a new line now?
During the replace step you add the newline character `\n` into the replacement string:

```
echo "Hi" > /tmp/file
echo "Hello" >> /tmp/file
echo "I am good." >> /tmp/file

sed -i 's/\(Hello\)/\1\ngot it/g' /tmp/file
```